# How to Add extra context for Class Based Login View?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I was previously using `Django==2.0.6` now I want to upgrade it to `Django==2.2.3`. And Doing some research I get to know that In django-2.1, the old function-based views of login, logout have been removed.

I still want to add some extra context to `LoginView` as per my project requirement..

Previously using Function Based View I have done the following:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.views import login as auth_views_login

def login(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Auth Login View
    """
    ecom_company = Ecom_Company.objects.filter(pk=1).first()
    landing_details = Landing.objects.filter(company=ecom_company).first()
    category_list = Categories.objects.filter(
        company=ecom_company).exclude(name__exact='Lab Test').order_by('id')
    partners_list = Partners.objects.filter(
        company=ecom_company).order_by('-id')
    stock_list = StockItem.objects.filter(
        organisation=ecom_company.organisation).order_by('id')

    context = {
        'ecom_company': ecom_company,
        'landing_details': landing_details,
        'category_list': category_list,
        'partners_list': partners_list,
        'stock_list': stock_list
    }

    return auth_views_login(*args, extra_context=context, **kwargs)
```

And in urls:

```
url(r'login/$', views.login,
        {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name="login"),
```

How do I pass the extra context for Class Based Login View as because `Django==2.2` does not support the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the LoginView like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

class MyLoginView(auth_views.LoginView):
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ecom_company = Ecom_Company.objects.filter(pk=1).first()
        landing_details = Landing.objects.filter(company=ecom_company).first()
        category_list = Categories.objects.filter(
        company=ecom_company).exclude(name__exact='Lab Test').order_by('id')
        partners_list = Partners.objects.filter(
        company=ecom_company).order_by('-id')
        stock_list = StockItem.objects.filter(
        organisation=ecom_company.organisation).order_by('id')
        context.update({
            'ecom_company': ecom_company,
            'landing_details': landing_details,
            'category_list': category_list,
            'partners_list': partners_list,
            'stock_list': stock_list
        }
        return context

# url
url(r'login/$', views.MyLoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
```